# Search for a tag didn't find the obvious result despite relevant synonyms and description text

Tags: bug, search, tag-synonyms

I searched at https://stackoverflow.com/tags for `windows forms` and the search for tags did not return the desired tag `winforms`.  There is even a tag synonym called `windows.forms`  I'm surprised this search isn't working.  To me it suggests that it is not searching the synonyms nor is it searching the full text of the tag description, which is:

> WinForms is the informal name given to Windows Forms, a GUI class library in the Microsoft .NET Framework and Mono. Questions in this tag should also be tagged with the target framework ([.net] or [mono]) and should ordinarily be tagged with a programming language tag.

Note that "Windows Forms" appears literally within the text.  Also the relevancy of the term "Windows Forms" to the tag "winforms" is inarguable, and could be derived from the text of questions that bear the tag.

I think this is a shortcoming of the tag search feature, and possibly a bug.

The actual results are:

- windows-forms-designer
- windowsformshost
- windowsformsintegration

Comment: SE search has never been working, so is this an actual bug, or intended behaviour?